# Optimización del código Python usando Numpy y Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
colum1 = [0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05]
colum2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
colum3 = [0.85,0.80,0.80,0.80,0.85,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
colum4 = [1743.85, 1485.58, 1250.07, 1021.83, 818.96, 628.05, 455.40, 319.03, 190.86 , 97.07, 26.96 , 0.00]
df = pd.DataFrame({
     'colum1' : colum1,
     'colum2' : colum2,
     'colum3' : colum3,
     'colum4' : colum4,
});
df['result'] = 0
for i in range(len(colum2)):
     df['result'] = np.where(
         df['colum2'] <= 5,
         np.where(
             df['colum2'] == 1,
             df['colum4'],
             np.where(
                 ( df['colum4'] - (df['result'].shift(1) * (df['colum1'] * df['colum3'])) )>0,
                 ( df['colum4'] - (df['result'].shift(1) * (df['colum1'] * df['colum3'])) ),
                 0
             )
         ),
         np.where(
             ( df['colum4'] - (df['result'].shift(1) * df['colum1']) )>0,
             ( df['colum4'] - (df['result'].shift(1) * df['colum1']) ),
             0
         )
     )
```

y necesito realizar la misma operación sin tener que recurrir a un ciclo. Esto sería muy útil, ya que estoy trabajando con miles de registros, lo cual es muy lento.

Mi resultado esperado es el siguiente:

```
    colum1  colum2  colum3   colum4       result
0     0.05       1    0.85  1743.85  1743.850000
1     0.05       2    0.80  1485.58  1415.826000
2     0.05       3    0.80  1250.07  1190.646800
3     0.05       4    0.80  1021.83   971.827200
4     0.05       5    0.85   818.96   775.532225
5     0.05       6    0.00   628.05   587.102000
6     0.05       7    0.00   455.40   426.044900
7     0.05       8    0.00   319.03   297.727755
8     0.05       9    0.00   190.86   175.973612
9     0.05      10    0.00    97.07    88.271319
10    0.05      11    0.00    26.96    22.546434
11    0.05      12    0.00     0.00     0.000000
```

Comment: Hola Yelson, hay errores en el código que impiden reproducirlo, falta un operador de comparación en principio en `df['colum2'] 0` y el segundo `np.where` no se sabe muy bien donde va ya que tal como está hay un error también con el ), que hay justo antes de el . Mira a ver si puedes corregirlo, al no explicar la operación que quieres es fundamental que al menos el código sea correcto para ver la lógica de la misma en el.

Comment: Gracias @FJSevilla, corregido.